# sencha touch 2 api docs

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm currently working on a project with Sencha Touch 2 and was wondering if anyone has a working link of the API docs page.

I've tried accessing http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api, but I'm constantly getting redirected to: https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/2-0/#!/api and am finally given a 'The page you’re trying to reach could not be found.' error from Sencha Touch's homepage.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I'm seeing the same link given on all my searches and hence I'm starting to get the feeling that this isn't just a faulty link problem, but perhaps something else.

--update--

The missing page error is occurring on Chrome. IE seems to be handling the link OK.

Comment: Strange... What if you access it from there : http://docs.sencha.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the error by disabling the KB SSL Enforcer extension in Chrome.

Hope this info. helps others facing the same problem.
The inability to read the docs in chrome was driving me mad for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you got that strange problem because the link is still Ok for me, maybe you need to clear your browser cache or something else.

But instead of that way, if you've already download and unzip the sencha touch 2 package from [here](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/) and I think you've already did it, so you just need to open the index.html file in that folder, the API docs are already there :)

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded the sdk right??? just go to your sdk folder and go to docs in your web browser the docs is right there...